# Input method is unable to get the action from Done button in android

Tags: android-input-method

1. I am trying to create an Input method, for which i am using
   softkeyboard example provided by the android sdk.
2. I install my application (apk file) on a samsung device (android
   2.1 sdk).
3. In the device i activate my IME and open the MEMO application. I
   change the orientation to landscape mode and type some words and the
   Click on the "Done" button which is at the right of the text.
4. When "Done" button is clicked, i am not able to understand, as
   which function of the InputMethod Service is getting called. Can you
   please help me on this.
5. Can you please tell me where the Control flows when such editor
   based buttons are called.